# lodash convert array of objects to single array of keys and multiple array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I need to transmit some data, that has too many key-value pairs.
As the keys are similar, I dont want to transmit them with each object.

Consider I have the following data:

```
[
    {
        x:11,
        y:12
    },{
        x:21,
        y:22
    },{
        x:31,
        y:32
    },{
        x:41,
        y:42
    }
];
```

And I need the final output as
`[ [x,y],[[11,12],[21,22],[31,32],[41,42]] ]` OR
`[ [x,y],[11,12],[21,22],[31,32],[41,42] ]`

On the other end, **I should be able to convert back to its original form**.
It would be great if it can **handle an additional key in some of the objects**

I think I have seen lodash or underscore function for something close/similar to this, but I'm not able to find it right now.

**NOTE: I don't know what the keys will be**

Comment: You need to show the example output for "an additional key in some of the objects". What would be the output when your data is `[{x:11,y:12},{x:21,y:22},{x:31,y:32},{x:41,y:42,a:0,b:0,c:0}]`?

Comment: @Amadan, I just wanted to compress and rebuild the data, without any loss. Its solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash v4.17.1

modify original

```
var modifiedOriginal = _.chain(original)
    .map(_.keys)
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .thru(function(header){
        return _.concat(
            [header],
            _.map(original, function(item) {
                return _.chain(item)
                    .defaults(_.zipObject(
                        header, 
                        _.times(_.size(header), _.constant(undefined))
                     ))
                     .pick(header)
                     .values()
                     .value()
            })
         );  
     })
     .value();
```

modified back to original (keys order is not 
guarantee)

```
var backToOriginal = _.map(_.tail(modified), function(item) { 
     return _.chain(_.head(modified))
         .zipObject(item)
         .transform(function(result, val, key) {
             if (!_.isUndefined(val)) {
                 result[key] = val;
             }
          })
          .value();
 });
```

JSFiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/wa8kaL5g/1/

Comment: back to original is not working. Also, it does not handle if one of the objects has an additional key

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var arr = [{
  x: 11,
  y: 12
}, {
  x: 21,
  y: 22
}, {
  x: 31,
  y: 32
}, {
  x: 41,
  y: 42
}];
var keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
var op = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  var arr = keys.reduce(function(x, y) {
    return x.concat([b[y]]);
  }, [])
  return a.concat([arr]);
}, [keys]); //If all the objects are having identical keys!
console.log(JSON.stringify(op));
```

Comment: but I dont know the keys, its runtime

Answer (score 1):

A little more verbose way of doing it:
[Edit: added the function to convert it back]

```js
function convert(arr) {
  var retArr = [ [/* keys (retArr[0]) */], [/* values (retArr[1]) */] ]
  arr.forEach(function(obj){
    // create new array for new sets of values
    retArr[1].push([])

    // put all of the keys in the correct array
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // does the key exist in the array yet?
        if (retArr[0].indexOf(key) === -1) {
          retArr[0].push(key)  
        }

        // get last index of retArr[1] and push on the values
        retArr[1][retArr[1].length - 1].push(obj[key])
      }
    }
  })

  return retArr
}


function reConvert(arr) {
  var retArr = []

  var keys = arr[0]

  arr[1].forEach(function(itemArr){
    var obj = {}
    itemArr.forEach(function(item, i){
      obj[keys[i]] = item
    })
    retArr.push(obj)
  })

  return retArr
}

var objArr = [
    {
        x:11,
        y:12
    },{
        x:21,
        y:22
    },{
        x:31,
        y:32
    },{
        x:41,
        y:42
    }
]

var arrFromObj = convert(objArr)
var objFromArr = reConvert(arrFromObj)

console.log(arrFromObj)
console.log(objFromArr)
```

Comment: I was going to use this as its native code,but some more testing revealed its not handling missing key. Definitely deserves a +1

Comment: Can you be more specific with the testing issue?

Comment: Didnt handle well when sequence of keys was changed, a key was removed and new were added.
`var objArr =[ { x: 11, y: 12 }, { x: 21, y: 22 }, { x: 31, asd: 33, z: 34 } ]`

Comment: I didn't know this was a requirement. In this case, you'll need to store some sort of value for each missing key...such as null...in the array of values so there is something to map it to. Did you find a solution for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes, 1 solution using lodash and underscore each. selected lodash as answer, but will probably use underscore solution as the code is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Underscore.

First work out what the keys are:

```
var keys = _.chain(data)
    .map(_.keys)
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

Then map across the data to pick out the value for each key:

```
var result = [
    keys, 
    _.map(data, item => _.map(keys, key => item[key]))
];
```

and back again:

```
var thereAndBackAgain = _.map(result[1], item => _.omit(_.object(result[0], item), _.isUndefined));
```

Lodash's version of [**object**](http://underscorejs.org/#object) is [**zipObject**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#zipObject) and [**omit**](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) using a predicate is [**omitBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#omitBy):

```
var thereAndBackAgain = _.map(result[1], item => _.omitBy(_.zipObject(result[0], item), _.isUndefined));
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        x:11,
        y:12,
        aa: 9
    },{
        x:21,
        y:22
    },{
        x:31,
        y:32,
        z: 0
    },{
        x:41,
        y:42
    }
];

var keys = _.chain(data)
 .map(_.keys)
 .flatten()
 .uniq()
 .value();

var result = [
 keys, 
 _.map(data, item => _.map(keys, key => item[key]))
];


var thereAndBackAgain = _.map(result[1], item => _.omit(_.object(result[0], item), _.isUndefined));

console.log(result)
console.log(thereAndBackAgain)
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It wont handle the scenario in which one of the object has an additional key

Comment: Tweaked to handle objects with differing keys

Comment: Object with additional keys may produce weird results. For example: [{ x: 8, y: 9 }, { a: 4, x: 2, y: 3 }] -> [['x', 'y', 'a'], [[8, 9], [4, 2, 3]] -> [{ x: 8, y: 9 }, { x: 4, y: 2, a: 3 }]

Comment: @OriDori I don't quite follow the example. The result would be `[[8,9,undefined], [2,3,4]]` which would then reconstitute to `[{x:8, y:9, a:undefined},{ x: 4, y: 2, a: 3 }]`

Comment: +1, couldnt select this as answer because the other guy gave lodash solution, and his rebuilding doesn't give `undefined` for missing fields.
I'll probably use your answer, less clutter than lodash

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can do it by reducing it with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). You can restore it using a combination of `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const convertStructure = (data) => data.reduce((s, item) => {
  s[1].push(Object.values(item));
  return s;
}, [Object.keys(data[0]), []]); // all objects should be the same, so we can take the keys from the 1st object

const restoreStructure = ([keys, data]) => data.map((item) => item.reduce((o, v, i) => {
  o[keys[i]] = v;
  return o;
}, {}));

const data = [{
  x: 11,
  y: 12
}, {
  x: 21,
  y: 22
}, {
  x: 31,
  y: 32
}, {
  x: 41,
  y: 42
}];

const convertedStructure = convertStructure(data);

console.log('convertedStructure:\n', convertedStructure);

const restoredStructure = restoreStructure(convertedStructure);

console.log('restoredStructure:\n', restoredStructure);
```